# How to bind a combobox with converter to a list in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Here I'm trying to bind the combobox to a List Codes. The combobox is displaying: A & B

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Codes}"/>

public SettingsWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Codes = new List<Code> {Code.A, Code.B};

    DataContext = this;
}
```

I have defined a converter to display a more understandable info in the combobox:

```
public class CodeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var code = (Code)value;

        string text;

        if (code == Code.A)
        {
            text = "ACI318-99";
        }
        else
        {
           text = "ACI318-11";
        }
        return text;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to use this converter in my XAML, so that I will have ACI318-99 & ACI318-11 in my combobox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should set the ItemTemplate of your Combobox, and use the Converter inside that.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Codes}">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource converterInstance}}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>          
</ComboBox>
```

here, converterInstance should be an instance of your custom converter in a resource dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

The Caliburn Micro convention is not that different but I just wanted to add it for future searchers. (Path=. is not needed in my case)

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyPropertyWithItems">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource converterInstance}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>          
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CodeConverter x:Key="CodeConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path="Codes" Converter="{StaticResource CodeConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer seems correct too, but in this case I will need to change my converter class to return a list I guess.